# How to cache AJAX Json data for 5 minutes?

Tags: jquery, wcf, caching

I am able to cache the AJAX data results but haven't been able to specify for how long.
Here is a partial code:

```
[OperationContract(Name = "Prepopulate_GetData")]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Prepopulate/GetData", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string GetData();

Client call:

function GetData() {
  $.ajax
  ({
      url: "svc/Prepopulate.svc/Prepopulate/GetData"
    , cache: true
...
```

Note: I cannot use the AspNetCacheProfile attribute because we are still on .Net 3.5 in this web application. That attribute only works for .Net 4.0 >

Also I have tried the code below in WCF but it didn't work:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.Private);
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: You have -1 which means expired upon creation and also remove SetNoStore, will you try:  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5));
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.Private);

Comment: would be nice if you marked my response if not as an answer than just by vote it up...